# The profile's dimensions are not respected in Curve To Mesh node

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, curve-modifier

I am trying to create a simple frame with exact dimensions using geometry nodes.
I created a rectangular curve of 0.3x0.2 m and then wanted to use a square profile curve of 0.1m width to get a final frame of 0.4x0.3 m, but it is smaller than expected.
Why are the dimensions of the profile curve not respected?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's rectangular, this *is* a curve. In *general*, for the radius of a swept curve to make sense, profiles must be instanced at the curve's sample-points, facing down the curve's linearly interpolated tangent, and *then* connected. The interpolated tangent at the corners of a rectangle are at 45°, and that's the angle and location of the profile-instances, before connection:

[image]

That means, between the comers, the connected sections measure `1/sqrt(2)` in that dimension. Multiply that dimension by `sqrt(2)` to get an orthogonal width of `1`, and stretch the diagonal mitres from `1` to `sqrt(2)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I absolutely missed that point, that Blender is instancing the profile at each point of the base curve. Now, it makes sense to me and I know how to overcome my problem!